# How to show only image on the url not other content even html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, web

I wan't to know "How to show only image on the url not other content even html?". Like see this url [link of Image](https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff). This url only shows image not any other content on webpage and also see the url of website it's dynamic url not a specific image url.

So, how to achieve that?

Comment: So many different ways to do this. It will depending on your set-up and server. A short version, echo a correct header and then binary data. Please update your question with enough information about your set-up and what you have tried so people can answer you correctly.

Comment: Yes @Tigger I, simply wants to server the image from the website

Answer (score 0):

You simply make the request to the URL of the image.

For example, if your image is called `test1.png` and you have it in a directory called `images`, you would make the URL like this:

`https://your.domain/images/test1.png`

If you want to *hide* the full path to the images and serve them through a page (so you have some control over the request for some reason), you can do something more like the following. Let's call the PHP page `img.php`. And the request could be like

`https://your.domain/img.php/test1`

```
<?php
$request = './default.png';
if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])){
    $request = './images'.$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'].'.png';
    if (! file_exists($request)){
        $request = './default.png';
    }
}

// we now know we have a valid request and the file was found
header('Content-type: image/png');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($request));
echo file_get_contents($request);
exit;
?>
```

With this approach you could have any number of images in the `/images/` directory and serve them if they match the request.

The website in your sample maybe using the same `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` info approach but would be dynamically creating the image using the passed variables and `explode('/',$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])`  along with [`imagecreate()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate)

A very quick hack version would be something like the following. The request would be like this:

`https://your.domain/test.php/100x50/919/222`

And the very quick code, with almost no error checking could be:

```
<?php
function hexToColor($hx){
    $rgb = array(0,0,0);
    if (strlen($hx) == 3){
        $rgb[0] = hexdec($hx[0].$hx[0]);
        $rgb[1] = hexdec($hx[1].$hx[1]);
        $rgb[2] = hexdec($hx[2].$hx[2]);
    } else {
        $rgb[0] = hexdec($hx[0].$hx[1]);
        $rgb[1] = hexdec($hx[2].$hx[3]);
        $rgb[2] = hexdec($hx[4].$hx[5]);
    }
    return $rgb;
}

// default values
$sizeW = 100;
$sizeH = 100;
$bg = array(0,0,0);
$fg = array(255,255,255);

if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])){
    $opts = explode('/',substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],1));
    $bgSet = false;
    foreach($opts as $k => $v){
        // check for a width x height request
        if (strpos($v,'x')){
            $tmp = explode('x',$v);
            $sizeW = $tmp[0];
            $sizeH = $tmp[1];
        } elseif ($bgSet){
            // must be a foreground request
            $fg = hexToColor($v);
        } else {
            $bg = hexToColor($v);
            $bgSet = true;
        }
    }
}

header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate($sizeW,$sizeH)
    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im,$bg[0],$bg[1],$bg[2]);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im,$fg[0],$fg[1],$fg[2]);
imagestring($im,1,5,5,$sizeW.' x '.$sizeH,$text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
exit;
?>
```

But I would strongly recommend a heap of error checking before using that code!

Answer (score -1):

As I understand you want to dynamically update the picture.

You can see that on their main website they created a form for the entered values:

[image]

After that, on the picture URL there are all the values you need to display this image:

`https://dummyimage.com/600x400/8a1a8a/232dba&text=xzcxzcnbngh`

which is this image:
[image]

what you can't see is their server side, which takes the parameters `600x400/8a1a8a/232dba&text=xzcxzcnbngh`, creates a picture using their server and returning it to you.

I'll suggest you to create a server side that will return a picture and text based on the given parameters.

based on your server you will need to find out how to create the picture and return it.

As you can see here, I just modified the "src" value of the  and it changed the text on the photo.

which means that their server receives the request and send back the image.

If you want a simple solution you could just send back those parameters to your page scripts, and create this image element using JavaScript.
That way, your html code will be clean without even the img element tag.

create your img in JS and send put it on the html body.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code ?

And what do you mean 'other' html page ? it shows it only on some html pages ? or none ?

Comment: @KfirRam : What you have shown is the placeholder HTML that the browser has included around the raw image request. I believe the OP simply wants to server the image from the website.

Comment: I just used similar approach but it does not show image on other html pages. I want to make similar website like this https://dummyimage.com/ but, I can't getting how this works? my basic concern is this how he can able to show image on the dynamic url not on a specific image url.

Comment: Yes @Tigger I, simply wants to server the image from the website

Comment: Do you want to serve it from the website ? using JS instead of using the server like they are doing ?

Answer (score -1):

Image placeholder that’s updated by scripting
HTML code:

```
<img id="abc" src="">
```

Javascript code:

```
var abcImage = document.getElementById('abc');
abcImage.src = 'https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff';
```

Comment: Please check it. It will work.

Comment: @Tejas above code will work. it will read dynamic image path